# Hive to store 140 digit long int

Tags: hive, biginteger, udf

I have a DB where an integer is of lenght 140 decimal digits (it may grow to couple of more digits over time). I dont have details on the data as it is coming from upstream system and it has to be passed to downstream as int.

Is there anyway to do it?

I tried to store it as string and create a view on top of it which converts to Java BigInteger using a UDF. But I don't find writable version BigInteger that I can use in Hadoop.

Any help pls.

Comment: Sounds very strange. **(1)** What kind of data is being described with 140 digits integer? **(2)** If the downstream can handle 140 digits integer can't it convert a string to integer?

Comment: You are out of luck: in Hive, BIGINT can store 19 digits max *(8-byte signed integer)* and DECIMAL(38,0) can store, well, 38 digits max. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal

Comment: Seems like data coming to you from your upstream system is concatination of different fields. Understand the structure and store in different column.

Comment: Thanks all. Converted to string, asked downstream to aware of it while consuming data.